# Regex to delete only one word in a phrase where multiple characters are matched in Notepad++

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I have a recurring word that pops up everywhere in a page of my that is right built into an HTML page. And I want to delete this word and this word only everywhere by using Regex in Notepad++.

The problem is, that the word is also part of another word, and when I try to delete it, the other word is partially deleted as well where the two letters are matched.

Here's an example:

```
<div>
<p>No November</p>
</div>
```

As you can see by my example I need to find a way to not delete November, but only the word No. Please state how I can do this.

Comment: search for 'No '.. add the space after 'No' and 'November' will not be touched.. for complex regex i actually use Dreamweaver.. it handles regex very well and it can also find and replace blocks of code rather than a line with notepad++.

Comment: I'm on Linux, so I can't use notepad++ right now. Can you check if `\<No\>` works? `\<` and `\>` should find the beginning and the end of a word. http://blog.creativeitp.com/posts-and-articles/editors/understanding-regex-with-notepad/

Answer (score 1):

You can type this into the replace box

```
Find what: (?<![a-zA-Z])[Nn][Oo](?![a-zA-Z])
Replace with:                                     //blank
```

With your example, it would look like this:

```
<div>
<p> November</p>
</div>
```

If you want spaces before or after to get removed as well, you could use this:

```
Find what: ( |(?<![a-zA-Z]))[Nn][Oo]( |(?![a-zA-Z]))
Replace with:                                     //blank
```

With your example, it would look like this:

```
<div>
<p>November</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a regular expression with `\b` placed before and after the search term:

So instead of `No`, search for `\bNo\b`. This should only find instances where No does not have anything before and after it, such as in 'November'.

Answer (score -3):

FIND: `(No)[\s\S]*?(november)[\s\S]*?`

REPLACE BY: `\2`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1027325)

Comment: is another solution, not critique. Just a point of view. Maybe I didn't understand the problem too well...Please test my solution, then write me back.

Comment: It is an answer, but I believe that it’s a wrong one. I believe that you misunderstood the question, but I agree that the question is badly presented and is easy to misunderstand.  As ***I*** understand it, the question has nothing to do with the word ‘‘November’’; that’s just a confusing example. I believe that the problem is to delete all occurrences of the word “no” without affecting words that contain “n” followed by “o”. So “now we have no waffles” should be changed to “now we have  waffles” rather than “w we have  waffles”. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … P.S. (1) Why do you need to put (the first) ``No`` into a capture group if you aren’t doing anything with it? (2) Does `[\s\S]` work in Notepad++? (I don’t have Notepad++, so I can’t test it, but `[\s\S]` is equivalent to `[sS\]` (i.e., match `s`, `S` or ``\``) in some other programs.) (3) If `[\s\S]` did work the way you seem to expect, wouldn’t it be the same as **`.`**? (4) If the question was what you seem to think it is, shouldn’t the character(s) after `november` be included in the capture group with `november`?

Comment: @Scott pay attention. The question was about notepad++, and as you say, you don't have notepad++. Also, you didn't test my solution. So, I believe your comment and rating should be deleted. My solution is very good, and your comment is in vain...

Comment: (5) You instruct me to pay attention.  What do you think I overlooked or ignored?  *As **you** pointed out,* I acknowledged that I cannot test your solution in the context of the question (i.e., Notepad++); that’s why I phrased my second comment as a clarifying question, followed by a factual statement that casts doubt on your solution.  I neglected to mention that (some) references on regular expressions say that the only special characters in a `[`…`]` are `^`, **`-`** and `]`.  Notably, they indicate that ``\`` is not special there. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (I didn’t mention it because I couldn’t immediately find one that addressed your specific usage. And, after further review, I see that some references conflict.)  But I have reconfirmed that, in some programs that recognize `\s` as space, `[\s]` matches ``\`` or `s`, but not space.  The fact that different programs that support regular expressions interpret them differently is discouraging, but, I guess, not shocking. (6) You have twice told readers to test your answer, but I don’t see you stating that *you* have tested it. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (7) But, even if my second comment is misguided, you haven’t addressed my other comments. For instance, if `[\s\S]` doesn’t match just ``\``, `s` or `S`, what *does* it match? Looks like it matches every possible character — so why not just use **`.`**?  (8) And so I got your command to ‘‘work’’ in `sed` by replacing `[\s\S]` with **`.`**. Given input of “I have had No waffles since november 17.”, it outputs “I have had november”. Can you justify deleting “waffles since”? Can you justify deleting “17”? The question says “I want to delete this word and this word only …”.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … P.S. You say that my comment and rating should be deleted. Well, for the reasons given above, I will not delete my comments. And I haven’t provided a “rating” yet — but I will now. … P.P.S. You can make all my comments disappear by deleting your answer.